# Exporting text from a cell into a function

Tags: text, google-sheets

I'm trying to extract the text "Sept" from cell H8 into a function of a google sheet.
The original function worked well:

`=if(isblank($B28), "", sumif('Sept Trans'!$E:$E,$B28,'Sept Trans'!$C:$C))`

But in order to replace "Sept", I tried this which worked:

`=if(isblank($B28), "", sumif(H8&' Trans'!$E:$E,$B28,'Sept Trans'!$C:$C))`

I tried to implement the next logical iteration, but it failed:

`=if(isblank($B28), "", sumif(H8&' Trans'!$E:$E,$B28,H8&' Trans'!$C:$C))`

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use INDIRECT:

```
=if(isblank($B28), "", sumif(INDIRECT("'" & H8 & " Trans'!$E:$E"),$B28,INDIRECT("'" & H8 & " Trans'!$C:$C")))
```